# Non-Abelian group of exponent $3$ and Nilpotent class $2$ .

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product, nilpotent-groups

Let $G$ be a non-Abelian group such that $G^3 = 1$ and $G$ is a nilpotent  class $2$ group, with order $3^{32}$. Our task is to determine the structure of the group $G$ or identify any information about the type of structure it possesses.

I only know that its structure will be something like a semi-direct product of cyclic groups of orders $3$, but I don’t know how many factors will be there. Like $C^{20}_3\rtimes C^{12}_3$ or something like $C^{10}_3\rtimes C^{10}_3\rtimes C^{12}_3.$

One more question is

Can I say that group $\mathbb Z^{k_{1}}_p\rtimes\mathbb Z^{k_2}_p\cdots\rtimes\mathbb Z^{k_r}_p$ ($p$is a fixed prime, $k_i\geq 2$) has  nilpotent $r$-class with non-trivial action?

Please help to resolve this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why $3^{32}$ exactly? In any case it's a good idea to think about $G/G'$ and $G'$, which are both elementary abelian, and the alternating bilinear map from $G/G'$ to $G'$ defined by the commutator.

Comment: @SeanEberhard yes it can be any $3^n$ order. Actually, I need that specific order that's why.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Can you tell me a little more about how many factors will be there?

Comment: @SeanEberhard I edited my question with one more question.

Comment: I think that you are asking the wrong question, and that @SeanEberhard has given you the right pointer.  You need to explore the alternating bilinear maps $V_n(\mathbb{F}_3)\to V_n(\mathbb{F}_3)$. [with $n=16$.] I think this sort of thing goes back to Higman's enumeration of $p$-groups, and I see more recent references to "UCS groups"

Comment: @ancientmathematician my last question is correct observation?

Comment: As you don't specify the semi-direct products you have in mind the question isn't well-posed. If the actions are trivial the class is $1$.

Comment: @ancientmathematiciannon non-trivial action so that the final group is non-abelian.

Comment: But there are many possible actions an elementary $p$-group on an elementary $p$ group

Comment: @ancientmathematician So if $G$ be a non-Abelian group such that $G^3 = 1$ and $G$ is a nilpotent  class $2$ group, with order $3^{32}$, then nothing can be said about $G$ decomposition?

Comment: @neelkanth Sean Eberhard has told you how to go about this, but you seem to keep going back to semidirect products, which are not the right way to approach this problem.

Comment: @DerekHolt I am not having good knowledge of that . I am trying to see on net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since nobody has attempted to answer the main question, I will do so. The number of isomorphism classes of groups satisfying the conditions is huge, and I don't believe that any kind of enumeration of these isomorphism classes is computationally feasible. It is possible to give a general description of these groups - the difficult problem would be to decide when two such groups are isomorphic.

For a group $G$ of this type, let $|G'|=3^m$  and $n=32-m$. Then $G$ can be generated by $n$ elements $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. To define $G$ we need to specify the value of the $n(n-1)/2$ commutators  $[x_i,x_j]$ with $1 \le i < j \le n$. Each such commutator is an element $z_{ij}$ of $G'$, where the $z_{ij}$ are required to generate $G'$.

Each such specification of the $z_{ij}$ defines a group in the class. If we write each $z_{ij}$ as a word in a generating set $y_1,\ldots,y_m$ of $G'$, then $G$ is defined by the presentation
$$\langle x_i\,(1 \le i \le n),\ y_j\,(1 \le j \le m) \mid x_i^3=y_j^3=[x_i,y_j]=1\, \forall i,j,\ [x_i,x_j]=z_{ij}\,\forall  i<j\rangle.$$
The requirement that the $z_{ij}$ generate $G'$ implies that $n \ge 8$, and we could consider the groups with $8 \le n \le 31$ as $24$ separate classes.

As I said above, deciding which of these groups are isomorphic is difficult and probably not computationally feasible because in principle we need to consider the actions of ${\rm GL}(n,3)$ and ${\rm GL}(m,3)$ on  $G/G'$ and $G'$.

But we can do some rough estimates (as was done by G. Higman in his proofs of lower bounds on the number of isomorphism classes of $p$-groups). The number of possible $z_{ij}$ without considering the generating $G'$ requirement is $3^{mn(n-1)/2}$,
but the vast majority of such choices will generate $G'$.

The number of such groups in any single  isomorphism class is at most $|{\rm GL}(n,3)||{\rm GL}(m,3)| \le 3^{m^2+n^2}$, so we get at least $3^{mn(n-1)/2-m^2-n^2}$ isomorphism classes which, for example with $n=21,\,m=10$, gives at least $3^{1748}$ isomorphism classes.

Comment: Thank you very much sir for giving your time.

Comment: Sir can I attach the link to a paper from where I got all of these problems?

Answer (score 3):

This is not really a serious answer but mainly an illustration of how useless is the idea of "some kind of semidirect product of groups of order 3".

Every group of exponent $3$ of order $3^{32}$ has the form $C_3 \rtimes C_3 \rtimes \cdots \rtimes C_3$ ($32$ factors).
Indeed, every finite group of exponent $p$ has the form $C_p \rtimes \cdots \rtimes C_p$.

*Proof:* Let $G$ be a finite group of exponent $p$. Since $G$ is nilpotent, its abelianization is nontrivial, so there is a nontrivial homomorphism $G \to C_p$. Since $G$ has exponent $p$, this map splits, so $G \cong H \rtimes C_p$ for some group $H$, and the claim follows by induction.

Comment: So its structure can't contains factor like  $C^2_3$?

Comment: One counter is $C^{20}_3\rtimes C^{12}_3.$

Comment: Its non abelian +nilptent+exponent $3.$

Comment: @neelkanth The point is that "semidirect product" is not uniquely defined without specifying the action. When you write "$C_3^{20} \rtimes C_3^{12}$", you haven't fully specified the group, but in any case this group also has the form $C_3 \rtimes \cdots \rtimes C_3$. The questions you are asking presume some sort of uniqueness of expression as a semidirect product which does not hold.

Comment: If $|G'|=3^m$, then you have a decomposition $C_3^m \rtimes C_3 \rtimes \cdots \rtimes C_3$, with $32-m$ factors $C_3$. For the overwhelming majority of groups of this type there is no shorter decomposition as a semidirect product.

Answer (score 1):

This should probably just be a comment but it is too complicated to write in the comment boxes.

Your second question has a special case:
*Has the group $\mathbb{Z}_p^k\rtimes \mathbb{Z}_p$ nilpotency class $2$?*

The answer to this is "No".

As an example, let $p\geqslant 3$, and $k=3$. Consider the semi-direct product $\mathbb{Z}_p^3\rtimes \mathbb{Z}_p$ in the concrete form

$$
\big\langle \begin{pmatrix}I & 0\\v &1 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}A & 0\\0 &1 \end{pmatrix} \mid v\in\mathbb{F}_p^3\big\rangle
$$
where $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0\\0& 1 &1\\0& 0 &1\end{pmatrix}$.

The nilpotency class is $3$. Replacing $3$ by any $k$ with $k\leqslant p$, and suitably adapting $A$ you will find examples of nilpotency class as great as $p$.

Comment: thank you very much.....

Comment: it will be true in the direct product. I  think.

Comment: The direct product is abelian so it has nilpotency class one.